# ML Modeling Recommendation for Predicting Snake Encounters in Historical Journey Data

Tags: classification, time-series, machine-learning-model, rnn, markov-hidden-model

I have a dataset consisting of historical journey data where individuals travel from point A to point B. During their journeys, they may encounter varying numbers of animal sightings, including snakes. The dataset includes attributes such as time, attribute_1, attribute_2, attribute_3, attribute_4, and a binary label indicating whether a snake was seen or not.

My objective is to create a website that can predict, based on a person's ID and their journey from point X to point Y, whether they are likely to encounter a snake during their next step. I want to choose the most suitable ML modeling approach for this task.

Considering the dynamic nature of the data, the need for real-time predictions, and the potential relevance of the previous snake sightings as additional information, I would like recommendations on which ML modeling techniques to explore. Additionally, I have additional attributes (attribute_1, attribute_2, etc.) that could potentially contribute to the prediction accuracy.

What ML modeling approaches would be most appropriate for this problem? Are there specific algorithms, architectures, or techniques that would be well-suited to handle this type of sequential prediction task?

Can the problem be solved by considering it as a time series classification problem and using the techniques such as LSTM RNN or HMM?

I would appreciate any insights, advice, or references to relevant research papers or tutorials that can help me make an informed decision.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

P.S.
The example of the data structure:

| id | time/step | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | attribute_3 | attribute_4 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | b | j | 10 | 105 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | b | h | 12 | 45 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | b | g | 12 | 454 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | y | j | 4 | 54 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | y | m | 7 | 65 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | x | l | 6 | 76 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | x | r | 99 | 99 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | x | e | 88 | 8 | 0 |
| 3 | 9 | x | w | 65 | 45 | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | x | f | 44 | 56 | 1 |
| 3 | 11 | x | h | 33 | 45 | 0 |

As can be seen each person might encounter a different number of animals, but what we know this number wouldn't be greater than 25. It depends on from and to where he/she travels. Label 0 means he/she sees an animal but it is not a snake, and 1 shows he/she sees a snake in that certain time/step.

This prediction is important because in the live system if we predict that the person will see the snake in the next step of his/her journey then we can notify him/her beforehand.

Comment: Whatever approach you choose, take into account the [survivor bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias) your data seems to have: you only have data on animal encounters, but lack data on "journeys not encountering any animals".

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I see your point and will take care of that. But what do you think about the approach I mentioned? Does it make sense to you or I'm in a completely wrong direction?

Comment: In my opinion, you would need A LOT of data to reliably predict something like that, given the amount of uncertainty. Therefore, I have doubts that it is possible to do it.

Comment: Thanks again for your fast response. Assuming I have enough data. I'm focusing on  the ML model. Can be the problem solved by considering it as time series classification problem and using the techniques such as RNN or HMM?

Comment: As I mentioned, I wouldn't know how to do it without data on not encountering any animals. Without such kind of data, I think you would only be able to predict the following: "if the person encounters an animal, would it be a snake or not?"

Comment: Actually, the aim of my project is what you mentioned: "if the person encounters an animal, would it be a snake or not?" and I'm trying to find out which ML approach fits to this problem the best. If you want to solve this problem, what method would you try?

Comment: It would highly depend on many factors about which you don't provide any information, e.g. what are `attribute_1`, `attribute_2`, etc, actually? Do you have geopositioning information of the encounters or the journeys? What is exactly `time/step`? This seems like a complex problem for which you need to actually use domain information rather than simply "throwing your data to a decent model".

Comment: Yes, I assume the problem is more complicated than I think. That is the reason I'm asking here to see other's opinion on such a problem. I want to be sure what I try to implement makes sense or not.
Time/step is actually the exact date and time (so month, year, weekday, can be all extracted). attribute_1 is simply the starting and ending point (ex. A-B), attribute_2 is soils type when the person sees the animal. Attribute_3 is latitude and attribute_4 is longitude.